# Does ctags for windows support .conf files

Tags: windows-7, gvim, ctags

I am trying to use the commands in the link below but i cant seem to get ctags to pick up the .conf file , is there a parameter I am supposed to use ?

http://weblogs.asp.net/george_v_reilly/archive/2009/03/24/exuberant-ctags-and-javascript.aspx

Comment: where did you place the .conf file? the article mentions $HOME (which is not set on windows per default) and ~ (which is an alias for $HOME on unix, though vim on windows understands it).

Comment: Yeah that is correct it turns out there is a parameter that called --options that accepts a file in which you can store your options ,once that is done everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a parameter that called --options that accepts a file in which you can store your options ,once that is done everything works fine. The file name can be called anything and example would be ctags.conf

Comment: I think it should be `ctags.cnf`